# How to give 'infinity' as a value to double through cin in C++?

Tags: c++, double, console-application, user-input, cin

In my program, I'm taking a slope value as input from the user. The code snippet looks like this:

```
double m;
std::cout << "Enter slope value:";
std::cin >> m;
```

But currently I'm unable to give 'infinity' as slope value to this. If type 'inf', m will store 0 maybe due to parse error. If I type really large number like 1e1000, m will store DBL_MAX i.e. 1.79769e+308.

So what should I type in console, so that m contains value of 'infinity'? (slope of vertical line).

Comment: Adopt a strategy like prompting "Enter slope or `inf` for infinity", reading a string, checking for `inf`, and if not use [`std::from_chars()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) to convert to double.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So what should I type in console, so that m contains value of 'infinity'? (slope of vertical line).

I don't think `std::istream::operator>>(double&)` currently supports that.

Ultimately it will use `std::strtod` to convert the extracted string to a `double` and `std::strtod` should accept `INF` and `INFINITY`, ignoring case and with optional `+`/`-` prefix.

However, currently the extraction of characters happens through [`std::num_get::do_get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get) which considers only the characters `0123456789abcdefpxABCDEFPX+-` as valid.

In [LWG 2381](https://wg21.link/lwg2381), which resolves some inconsistencies between `>>` and `strtod`, inifinities and NaNs are also mentioned as not in scope of the resolution.

So you'll need to read in a string and call `std::strtod`/`std::stod`/`std::from_chars` on it manually.